# Возвращение std::string_view из метода

Tags: c++, строки, c++17

У меня есть класс, хранящий вектор строк `std::vector<std::string>`. Как лучше определить его метод, возвращающий элемент по индексу?

Так?

```
[[nodiscard]] std::string get_by_index(size_type index) const;
```

Так?

```
[[nodiscard]] std::string_view get_by_index(size_type index) const;
```

Или как-то по-другому?

Comment: Можно в любом варианте. Если вы используете 17 стандарт, то второй вариант предпочтительнее, особенно если строки достаточно большого размера.

Comment: тут(и не только тут) нельзя сказать что лучше. Невозможно знать намерения программиста. Если вам придется выполнять какие то изменения в строке, то придется опять преобразовывать в std::string.   В первом варианте с современными правилами и компиляторами ничего не копируется, а просто конструируется std::string с такими же данными

Comment: @ARHovsepyan новая строка имеет отличный от строки в векторе внутренний массив символов, это и есть копия

Comment: Я лишь скажу еще раз _ нет лучшего способа, код должен отражать ваши намерения...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan первый способ всегда копирует, а второй - не всегда. Независимо от намерений.

Comment: хорошо, как скажете

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если возвращать `std::string`, то строка всегда будет копироваться.
Небольшой плюс этого: пользователь не сможет поменять оригинальную строку `const_cast`-ом, даже если захочет. Но это уже паранойя...

Если возвращать `std::string_view`, то копии не будет. Но `string_view` вы не сможете передать (без копирования строки) в функцию, которой нужна строка с нулевым байтом на конце. Или в функцию с параметром `const std::string &`.

Третий вариант - возвращать `const std::string &`. Здесь не будет копирования, и вы всегда можете создать `string_view` из ссылки на строку, если захотите.
Небольшой минус: если вы вдруг захотите переделать класс, чтобы хранить строки не в `std::string` а где-то еще, то это можно будет сделать только изменив интерфейс.

---

Я бы использовал `const std::string &`.

Comment: Поясните про нулевой байт, пожалуйста. Могу ли я использовать `std::string_view::data()` для конструктора `std::ifstream`, например? Там нужен нулевой байт.

Comment: Все функции с параметром `const std::string &` я уже перевёл в функции с параметром `std::string_view` в моём коде.

Comment: @ueber На `string_view` могли дернуть `.remove_suffix()` - тогда нулевой байт может быть не в конце строки, а дальше. Или `string_view` могли сконструировать из массива символов, в котором нулевого байта вообще нет.

Comment: Ну а если мой класс просто возвращает значения из вектора `std::string`, без какой-либо их обработки, то такого не могло произойти. А что дальше пользователь делает с `std::string_view` мне уже неважно. Тогда минусов нет у второго варианта? Или он будет медленее, чем по константной ссылке?

Comment: @ueber Минус в том, что это неочевидно. Вам тогда нужно везде втыкать комметарии с пояснениями, что *именно здесь* у вас `string_view` с нулем на конце. *"Или он будет медленее, чем по константной ссылке?"* Сомневаюсь, что будет большая разница, но вы проверьте, если вам важно.

Comment: "Если возвращать std::string, т о строка всегда будет копироваться."? не  согласен. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17#%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: "не согласен." - обязательный copy elision не относится к указанному случаю вообще никак.